# AWS lambda query on Athena returns nothing

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to make a Python script containing a query to my Athena database (I created an Amazon S3 bucket as an output). I saw some basics tutorials to do so, and got this code :

```
import json
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    QueryResponse = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = "SELECT id FROM table;",
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database' : 'raw'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation' : 's3://mybucket/'
       }
    )


    #Oberserve results : 
    queryId = QueryResponse['QueryExecutionId']
    time.sleep(10)

    results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    for row in results['ResultSet']['Rows']:
        print(row)
```

This code is supposed to print data retrieved by the query. But when I run it, I have this error message :

```
    Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the 
GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED",
  "errorType": "InvalidRequestException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    results = 
client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return 
self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise 
error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I tried to run the query on Athena to see if it was returning data and the query works perfectly. I also tried to run the code without the part writter after : '#Observe results :' and it seems that my code doesn't return anything because the response is just 'null'. I don't understand why or where the problem comes from.
Any ideas or suggestions about what I should do ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you inspect the history of the primary workgroup in athena, what does the UI tell you why the query failed?

Comment: tablename table?

Comment: I got this : Your query has the following error(s):

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

Comment: Does this mean I do not have a role with the right access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just checked the history in Athena and it was actually an Amazon S3 permission problem. I did add the role I use permissions on S3 and it works fine.